# Add advanced filter to accordion and order the accordion alphabetically in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filter, accordion

Here is the scenario: I am trying to have the whole profile of an international organization listed in an accordion list. So, when people click on the organization's name they can see the information when it expands. 
[This is what I am talking about (please see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnT9v.png)

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
1. Create an advanced filter that can filter the organizations by region of work.
2. Order the accordion alphabetically automatically

Please I am open to ideas and suggestions about how to do this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I assume you fill the accordion from a database. When you retrieve the database records the right way, you don't need a filter.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myItems = [
{ name: 'test', region: 'US' },
{ name: 'message', region: 'US' },
{ name: 'new message', region: 'EU' },
{ name: 'a message', region: 'EU' },
]

function compareItems(a, b) {
    var aVal = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var bVal = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return aVal  < bVal ? -1 : aVal > bVal ? 1 : 0;
}

function filterEU(value) {
    return value.region === 'EU';
}

var sortedItems = myItems.sort(function(a,b) {
 return compareItems(a,b);
})

var filteredItems = myItems.filter(filterEU);

console.log(sortedItems);
console.log('-------------')
console.log(filteredItems);
```

You can of course let the filterRegion function get the currently filtered region from somewhere to make it less static.

The alphabetical sorting does a lowercase to make it ignore casing, as it would otherwise sort lower and upper case behind each other. Unless you want that you should keep it.